# Pug is not correctly generating the HTML even with the correct pug indentation

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, pug

I have the following code in Pug which generates the following HTML code:

```
    - var n = 0
    each street in streets
        if n % 4 == 0
            - n = 0     
            .w3-row-padding
        if n < 4
                .w3-col.l3.m6.w3-margin-bottom
                    .w3-display-container
                        .w3-display-topleft.w3-black.w3-padding 
                            a(href="/ruas/"+street._id) #{street.nome}
                        - var streetName = street._id + "-" + street.nome.replace(/\s/g, "")
                        img(src="/dados/materialBase/atual/"+ streetName +"-Vista1.JPG",alt="House", style="width:100%;height:400px;object-fit: cover;")
        - n = n+1
```

The resulting HTML code:

```
<div class="w3-row-padding"></div>
<div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
<div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
<div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
<div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
```

And what I actually want it to generate:

```
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

So my question is, what is wrong with this approach in Pug and how can we generate the correct HTML code? I'm indenting the code correctly but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What if you indent `if n < 4` (and the nested code) further than `.w3-row-padding`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it doesn't work either, it even gets worse.

Comment: put `.w3-row-padding` outside the each loop?

Comment: @evolutionxbox But I need it to generate a new row every 4 loops.

Comment: Contrary to your question title, that's not the correct Pug indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a crude solution but it seems to work:

```
.w3-row-padding
    - for(let r=n ; r< n + 4 ; r++)
        if(streets[r])
            .w3-col.l3.m6.w3-margin-bottom
                .w3-display-container
                    .w3-display-topleft.w3-black.w3-padding 
                        a(href="/ruas/"+streets[r]._id) #{streets[r].nome}
                    img(src="/images/dados/materialBase/atual/"+ streets[r].nome +"-Vista1.JPG",alt="House", style="width:100%;height:400px;object-fit: cover;")
                    - n = n+1
```

Answer (score 1):

The indentation must be this:

Depending on whether you use tabs or spaces as indentation, you have to adjust it when you copy it.

```
- var n = 0
each street in streets
    if n % 4 == 0
        - n = 0     
        .w3-row-padding
            if n < 4
                .w3-col.l3.m6.w3-margin-bottom
                    .w3-display-container
                        .w3-display-topleft.w3-black.w3-padding 
                            a(href="/ruas/"+street._id) #{street.nome}
                        - var streetName = street._id + "-" + street.nome.replace(/\s/g, "")
                        img(src="/dados/materialBase/atual/"+ streetName +"-Vista1.JPG",alt="House", style="width:100%;height:400px;object-fit: cover;")
    - n = n+1
```